# MCP4725 not working

Tags: arduino-mega

I tried using a MCP4725 DAC with an Arduino (M0 Pro, Duemilanove and Diecimila) and it is not outputing any voltage (just random noise).

I've been using the 2 tutorial codes fount here : https://learn.adafruit.com/mcp4725-12-bit-dac-tutorial/using-with-arduino which are supposed to generate a sinus wave and a triangle wave.

I am pretty sure it doesn't come from the Arduino because basic examples have been working so far.

Anybody had the same issue or can help on this ?

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MCP4725.h>

Adafruit_MCP4725 dac;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello!");

// For Adafruit MCP4725A1 the address is 0x62 (default) or 0x63 (ADDR pin tied to VCC)
  // For MCP4725A0 the address is 0x60 or 0x61
  // For MCP4725A2 the address is 0x64 or 0x65
  dac.begin(0x62);

  Serial.println("Generating a triangle wave");
}

void loop(void) {
    uint32_t counter;
    // Run through the full 12-bit scale for a triangle wave
    for (counter = 0; counter < 4095; counter++)
    {
      dac.setVoltage(counter, false);
    }
    for (counter = 4095; counter > 0; counter--)
    {
      dac.setVoltage(counter, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know its not outputting what you expect?  Have you tried outputting a constant voltage and measuring that?  What does the second parameter do?

Comment: I have an electrometer on the output.

Yes.

2nd parameter is a storeflag that indicates to the DAC whether it should store the value in EEPROM so that next time it starts, it'll have that same value output. You shouldn't set the flag to true unless you require it as it will take longer to do, and you could wear out the EEPROM if you write it over 20,000 times.

Comment: The output you are generating is a triangle wave, as it states in the program. To see that you need an oscilloscope. I haven't seen an Electrometer since the 18th century.

Comment: So if i just do `dac.setVoltage(1000,false);` I should get a constant voltage on the electrometer right ?

Comment: Maybe on a voltmeter you might, yes. Please call it what it is, not what it was known as 200 years ago. Unless you really have got your hands on a modern electrometer, in which case you must have huge amounts of spare cash lying around.

Comment: It's written electrometer on it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this example to work.

Details:

My A0 line was tied to ground using the solder jumper (through a 10k SMD resistor on the board it appears).
I used . . .

## define MCP4725_ADDR 0x62

. . . as the base address of the chip.
My CMD to update the DAC was . . .

Wire.write(64);

. . . (64 in decimal i.e. 0b01000000)

This YouTube video helped out a lot:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngvqgIeaS9M

All the best
KenLaszlo